# why return print('string') invoke syntax error in pylint

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

i am running pylint 1.1.0-1 on ubuntu 14.04

my code passed all checking with python 3.4 and runs well.

however checked with pylint it invokes syntax error for the following line:

```
if not (os.path.exists(d1)and os.path.exists(d2)):
  return print('\npaths not found\n')
```

why?!

because pylint found error, it did not continue to deliver report and stats.

Comment: Well... it's not a syntax error... but `return print` does seem really pointless as it's nothing more than `return None`... which'll happen if you fall off the end of the function without returning anything anyway... It's a bit confusing as to whether you really mean to be `print`ing the string or whether you're intending to `return` the string... Maybe pylint is just saying it doesn't make sense?

Comment: I'd suggest for a start you do `pylint --version` and ensure it's a Python 3 variant.

Comment: Also, the full list of error codes is on http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes - might want to look up the exact reason pylint is piping up

Comment: @JonClements, isn't it common to print an error msg when exiting a function? something like return errormsg(error_code) to call an error msg handling function?

Comment: @timeislove no - not really. I suppose `return errormsg(error_code)` which returns something other than `None` would make more sense than `return print(...)` albeit it not really Pythonic. If there's an error, raise a suitable exception and let the caller handle it...

Comment: @paxdiablo, i did pylint --version, it told python 2.7.6 (default, mar 2014). but this version of pylint checked no problem with all other print() in my python3 codes. and the pylint said it supports python >2.2 , isn't it?

Comment: @JonClements, to me errormsg(error_code) may not return any meaningful at all. do u mean that return print would simply return a value of None, while return custom function would return some real value, because we may set to return 0/1 when exiting that custom function?!

Comment: @timeislove well, it'd return whatever the function returns... However, I'll say again, if you're using return codes to indicate success/failure you're not utilising Python correctly - more writing C (or similar) using Python... That's what *exception handling* is for...